# pdsh: how to run a commands that require root/sudo privileges

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, root

I have implemented a small beowulf cluster for testing purpose, all nodes with Ubuntu server 18.04.

I have installed `pdsh` for running the same command on ssh at the same time on multiple node.
ssh login is granted passwordless with public/private key distribution over the nodes (example: https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2014/12/linux-cluster-sysadmin-ssh-keys/) .

If I try a simple command like "date" , all is fine:

```
me@master:~$ pdsh -w me@node[0-3] date
node0: Mon Mar 9 18:56:04 UTC 2020
node2: Mon Mar 9 17:26:15 UTC 2020
node3: Mon Mar 9 16:42:37 UTC 2020
node1: Mon Mar 9 17:42:52 UTC 2020
me@master:~$
```

But if I try a command that require a sudoer privileges like this:

```
me@master:~$ pdsh -w me@node[0-3] apt update
```

then it returns these errors:

```
node0: WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
node0:
node0: Reading package lists...
node0: E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
node0: E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
node0: W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
node0: W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
pdsh@node00: node0: ssh exited with exit code 100
```

and so on for all other nodes.

The problem is the "apt update" command that require a sudo execution but I have not found a way to pass it with pdsh

The same kind of commands launched with "real" root user runs fine:

```
root@master:~$ pdsh -w root@node[0-3] apt update
```

But in this case this means actually enabling the "real" root user on all nodes, which I would like to avoid.

Is it posssible? Is there a way for running elevated privileges commands with `pdsh` without enabling the root user? Or are there alternative tools that can do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't run `pdsh -w me@node[0-3] sudo apt update`? Will it not ask for a password or something?

Comment: If I run :
 
me@node0:~$ pdsh -w me@node[0-3] sudo apt update

This is the results:

node0: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
pdsh@node0: node0: ssh exited with exit code 1
...

And so on for nodes 1, 2  and 3 :-\

B.

Comment: Thanks, it's just a guess but try this instead: `pdsh -w me@node[0-3] sudo -S apt update` If you still have trouble, try this: `pdsh -w me@node[0-3] echo "password\n" | sudo -S apt update` but replace `password` with your actual password and don't forget to put the new line character: `\n` after, as [this is needed](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.3/sudo.man.html#S).

Comment: Please let me know if this works and I will make it an answer. However, I will keep looking for a better solution in case you don't want your password in plaintext like this.

Comment: Running ```pdsh -w me@node[0-3] sudo -S apt update``` the bash freezes waiting for something, then ctr-c : ```interrupt,.. command in progress node0```... and nothing happens (other 2 ctrl-c for interrupt). For ```pdsh -w me@node[0-3] echo "password\n" | sudo -S apt update``` I think there is a typo, there must be a space, like this: ```pdsh -w me@node[0-3] echo "password" \n | sudo -S apt update```; in any case the result is: ```[sudo] password for me: Sorry, try again.``` (3 times) and: ```[sudo] password for me: sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts``` Naturally the password is correct

Comment: where "password" is replaced with the actual password without " "

Comment: My bad, the `\n` is not needed so `pdsh -w me@node[0-3] echo "password" | sudo -S apt update` should work instead. Also, you can put a blank space before the `pdsh` command to prevent your password from showing up in your bash history.

Comment: where `password` is replaced with your actual password. You might need to use quotation marks if your password contains certain characters.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `-S` flag to pipe your password to `sudo` like this:

```
pdsh -w me@node[0-3] echo "password" | sudo -S apt update
```

where `password` is your actual password.

Also, you can prevent your password from showing up in your `~/.bash_history` by placing the following line in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export HISTIGNORE='*sudo -S*'
```

and don't forget to source your `~/.bashrc` file to apply the changes:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

You may need to do this on all machines.

Comment: Sorry... well there is something strange, if: ```pdsh -w me@node[0-3] echo "password" | sudo -S apt update ``` the results is: ```[sudo] password for me: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for bed: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for bed: sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts``` as an incorrect password, but isn't :-/ I have read a similar solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error) but for a ssh problem

Answer (score 0):

Running on Red Hat, I run commands that require elevated privileges like this:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/pdsh -w node[n-m] ?command
```

This should work as long as root has ssh access to other nodes.